# When and why it's better to pass simple types by value or reference in rust

Tags: rust

Considering example struct with few common types and getters for them, when and why it's better to pass simple types by value or reference in rust?

```
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
pub type Bytes = [u8; 16];
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Uuid(Bytes);


struct X {
    v_str: String,
    v_num: i32,
    v_bool: bool,
    v_uuid: Uuid,
    v_date: DateTime<Utc>,
}
impl X {
    pub fn v_str_ref(&self) -> &str {
        &self.v_str
    }
    pub fn v_str_val(&self) -> String {
        self.v_str.clone()
    }

    pub fn v_num_ref(&self) -> &i32 {
        &self.v_num
    }
    pub fn v_num_val(&self) -> i32 {
        self.v_num
    }

    pub fn v_bool_ref(&self) -> &bool {
        &self.v_bool
    }
    pub fn v_bool_val(&self) -> bool {
        self.v_bool
    }

    pub fn v_uuid_ref(&self) -> &Uuid {
        &self.v_uuid
    }
    pub fn v_uuid_val(&self) -> Uuid {
        self.v_uuid
    }

    pub fn v_date_ref(&self) -> &DateTime<Utc> {
        &self.v_date
    }
    pub fn v_date_val(&self) -> DateTime<Utc> {
        self.v_date
    }
}
```

From my understanding numbers is better to be passed as value because reference overhead makes performance worse versus just passing by value, also borrow checker rules make passing by reference inconvenient.

Booleans seems follow numbers logic.

For string it seems performance is better when passed by reference and it's simple just to clone when borrow checker stands in a way.

For uuid and dates I would assume same rules as for string apply?

Comment: Keep in mind that simple functions that accept a reference will often be inlined and the reference will be elided.

Comment: @cdhowie and what does this imply/change?

Comment: It implies that, for most simple cases, both options will perform the same because the compiler can usually elide the reference. And when the reference can't be elided, because of Rust's aliasing rules, the optimizer may cache the referent value in a register if it is used frequently. In Rust we know that the target of a `&` can't be mutated (absent the presence of a cell) and therefore the referent can be more aggressively cached than other compiled languages may permit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple integers, floating point numbers, and booleans, usually passing by value is better because, as you mentioned, they're typically small.  Also, they're typically `Copy`, so the compiler is typically making tons of copies of them anyway (which it will hopefully elide in the optimized output).

The standard library also has IP addresses as `Copy`, which are about 16 bytes.  Once you get data larger than that, it's often useful to pass references, since a pointer is only 4 or 8 bytes (and can fit in a register) and larger values can't, so there's more overhead to copy them.

Since the data in a String or Vec can be nearly arbitrarily large, it's often prudent to use the appropriate reference type (`&str` or `&[T]`) because that prevents needing to copy all the data.  Often, these values contain small numbers of items, but if your String contains even the contents of a StackOverflow post, making lots of copies can get pretty slow pretty fast.  Similarly, that's true for most general arbitrary collections unless you're certain the data is always small.

Comment: The tl;dr of this answer: if the type doesn't implement `Copy`, pass a reference. If it is `Copy` and is small enough to fit into a register or two, pass a copy. In all other cases, benchmark if performance matters.